# Even better support for HAML in Netbeans?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, netbeans, haml, sass

[This plugin](http://mediacast.sun.com/users/tnorbye/media/org-netbeans-modules-haml.nbm/details) is pretty good, definitely better than plain-text.. but I'm longing for a little more. Code completion, the Netbeans code generator shortcuts, 'ri' integration for looking up documentation like the .erb files have..

Does anyone have some tricks, is there a different plugin for this type of functionality in Netbeans?

Definitely would like SASS support for Netbeans as well!

Comment: I would also love to see even better Sass support in the mentioned plugin.

Comment: I'm in! We do need better SASS/HAML support in Netbeans

Comment: The link is broken now, I have tried to search for the plugin to no avail. Do you have an updated link for this plugin?

Answer (score 8):

Here http://code.google.com/p/postcomment/downloads/detail?name=org-netbeans-modules-haml.nbm&can=2&q=

Answer (score 5):

Everybody seems to be craving for proper Netbeans HAML/SASS support.
Let's motivate someone to code it :

http://www.donanza.com/jobs/p1413667-software_development_netbeans_haml_support_plugin

Comment: +1 for that, I would even say it would be nice if netbeans had a compass plugin as well.

Answer (score 3):

I came across a problem in the HAML-plugin by Dylan Bruzenak (the one up on google) that it wouldn't recognize the new Ruby 1.9 hash syntax in HTML attributes.

So I did some hacking and modified the haml.nbs inside `<nbm>/netbeans/modules/<org-netbeans-modules-haml.jar>/org/netbeans/modules/haml` to support this.

Replace line 50 with

```
TOKEN:ruby_symbol:((':' [^ ' ' '=' '}' '"']+) | ([^ ':' '}' '"']+ ':'))
```

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! I got it to work with NB 8

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about a new IDE:

RubyMine is popular, try that. http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You can find it here: http://code.google.com/p/postcomment/downloads/detail?name=org-netbeans-modules-haml.nbm&can=2.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin is basic, but note that Oracle seem to be closing down the mediacast site where it is hosted. Has development/distribution been moved to another site? I am quite dependent on this plugin for haml work, and I would like to see a future for it.

Answer (score 0):

There's an haml plugin that needs some teaks in order to change the default colors: [How to change color of HAML tags in NetBeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598553/how-to-change-color-of-haml-tags-in-netbeans)