# How to change color of HAML tags in NetBeans?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, netbeans, colors, syntax-highlighting, haml

I use Aloha theme in NetBeans 6.8, everything looks cool except these blue tags in HAML files, which are unreadable. How to find a place where this blue color could be changed?

P.S. I use that HAML plugin which seems to be unsupported and lacks features

Screenshot: http://img.leprosorium.com/846904 (sorry, new users can't embed images)

Answer (score 2):

Sad to say "that HAML plugin which seems to be unsupported and lacks features", is the only Haml plugin there is for netbeans. I don't know if there is source code for it out there either (never looked). If you look, the colours are all defined in a file called haml.nbs. You can find it by extracting the org.netbeans.haml.jar from the nbm you downloaded and then extracting the haml.nbs from that. Ubuntu's file-roller will cheerfully do this for you.
The contents of the file look like this:

```
COLOR:declaration: {
default_coloring: "comment";
foreground_color: "gray";
}
...
```

With a little fiddling you could probably change those values to suit your needs and put it back together. It should work.
Of course if there was source for the darn thing that would be even better.

Comment: Wonderfull! I went to that file and replaced every /00/ for "aa". Now the colors are very nice!

Answer (score 2):

Lots of people would DIE for a decent Netbeans HAML plugin.

I suggest that we just PAY for someone to write it :

http://www.cofundos.org/project.php?id=181

Comment: here is another donation page: http://www.donanza.com/jobs/p1413667-software_development_netbeans_haml_support_plugin