# Netbeans 6.9 support for HAML and SASS?

Tags: netbeans, haml, sass

It doesn't seem to be any HAML and SASS support in Netbeans 6.9.

Is there a way to add this support?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went to the NetBeans Plugin Portal and searched for HAML and found some results there: http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/faces/PluginListPage.jsp?search=haml

This query produces many results that imply that there is support for HAML and SASS available:
http://www.google.com/search?q=haml+netbeans+support

If none of the projects that are available meet your needs, you may want to consider joining one of the open source HAML/SASS development support plugin projects and contributing coding/qa/documentation/whatever to the project.

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/postcomment/downloads/detail?name=org-netbeans-modules-haml.nbm&can=2&q=

Somewhere in the project page there were once some comments regarding how to edit the color scheme by editing a certain file.

Answer (score 0):

There's an haml plugin that needs some teaks in order to change the default colors:
[How to change color of HAML tags in NetBeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598553/how-to-change-color-of-haml-tags-in-netbeans)